# How To Post Multiple Objects from View To dot net core 6 MVC Controller using ajax jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have tried to solve the issue but I cannot figure it out I don't know what a problem in my code I want to post this form with the objects tell me what I'm missing in it any help will be appreciated!
Here is my script

```
 function getInvoiceObject() 
      {
    var Invoice = new Object();
    //var form = $('#Invoice-Form')[0];
    //const formData = new FormData(form);
    Invoice.InvoiceId = $('#InvoiceId').val();
    Invoice.InvoiceTemplateId = $('#InvoiceTemplateId').val();
    Invoice.InvoiceDueAfterDays = $('#InvoiceDueAfterDays').val();
    Invoice.DefulatTerms = $('#DefulatTerms').val();
    Invoice.DefaultFooter = $('#DefaultFooter').val();
    return Invoice;
      }
      
      function getEmailObject() 
      {
          var Email = new Object();
          Email.EmailId = $('#EmailId').val();
          Email.InvoiceEmailBody = $('#InvoiceEmailBody').val();
          Email.OverDueInvoiceEmailBody = $('#OverDueInvoiceEmailBody').val();
         return Email;
      }
      

      function SaveAllSettings()
      {
debugger;
          var InvoicesVM = getInvoiceObject();
          var EmailVM    = getEmailObject();
         // var AllSettings = [];
         // AllSettings.push(Invoices);
         // AllSettings.push(Email);
           var AllSettings = {InvoicesVM:InvoicesVM, EmailVM: EmailVM};
           //console.log(postData);
          $.ajax({
                //dataType: 'json',
               // async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Settings/SaveAllSettings",              
                data: '{ "AllSettings":' + JSON.stringify(AllSettings) + '}', 
                processData: false,
                traditional: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (response) {
                  toastr.success('Saved SuccessFully!');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                  //toastr.error('Cannot Save the Data!');
                }
            })

      }
```

And here is my Controller

```
           
        [HttpPost]
       public JsonResult SaveAllSettings(SettingsVM AllSettings)
        {
           
            return Json("");
        }
```

And here is my ViewModel class

```
 public class SettingsVM
    {
        public InvoiceSettingsVM InvoicesVM { get; set; }
        public EmailSettingsVM EmailVM { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're manually building a JSON string containing another JSON string, which is the root cause of your problem. To fix this provide a plain JS object to the `data` property of the `$.ajax()` invocation.

```js
data: { 
  InvoicesVM: InvoicesVM, 
  EmailVM: EmailVM
},
```

Here's a complete example with a few other syntax/good practice improvements:

```js
let getInvoiceObject = () => ({
  invoiceId = $('#InvoiceId').val(),
  invoiceTemplateId = $('#InvoiceTemplateId').val(),
  invoiceDueAfterDays = $('#InvoiceDueAfterDays').val(),
  defulatTerms = $('#DefulatTerms').val(), // typo in property name/element id here...?
  defaultFooter = $('#DefaultFooter').val(),
})

let getEmailObject = () => ({
  emailId = $('#EmailId').val(),
  invoiceEmailBody = $('#InvoiceEmailBody').val(),
  overDueInvoiceEmailBody = $('#OverDueInvoiceEmailBody').val(),
})

let saveAllSettings = () => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Settings/SaveAllSettings",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
      invoicesVM: getInvoiceObject(), 
      emailVM: getEmailObject()
    }, 
    traditional: true, // probably not needed here
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      toastr.success('Saved SuccessFully!');
    },
    error: function(msg) {
      //toastr.error('Cannot Save the Data!');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Will implement and come back to you Thanks in advance

Comment: well thanks for ur help but it still not binding emailvm and invoicevm in controller

Comment: The root object `allSettings` doesn't need to be named in the json; `data: { InvoicesVM: InvoicesVM, EmailVM: EmailVM }` But you will need `[FromBody]`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks for pointing that out -not sure how I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo to pass json type data to action with ajax:

js:

```
function getInvoiceObject() 
      {
    var Invoice = new Object();
    //var form = $('#Invoice-Form')[0];
    //const formData = new FormData(form);
    Invoice.InvoiceId = $('#InvoiceId').val();
    Invoice.InvoiceTemplateId = $('#InvoiceTemplateId').val();
    Invoice.InvoiceDueAfterDays = $('#InvoiceDueAfterDays').val();
    Invoice.DefulatTerms = $('#DefulatTerms').val();
    Invoice.DefaultFooter = $('#DefaultFooter').val();
    return Invoice;
      }
      
      function getEmailObject() 
      {
          var Email = new Object();
          Email.EmailId = $('#EmailId').val();
          Email.InvoiceEmailBody = $('#InvoiceEmailBody').val();
          Email.OverDueInvoiceEmailBody = $('#OverDueInvoiceEmailBody').val();
         return Email;
      }
      

      function SaveAllSettings()
      {
debugger;
          var InvoicesVM = getInvoiceObject();
          var EmailVM    = getEmailObject();
         // var AllSettings = [];
         // AllSettings.push(Invoices);
         // AllSettings.push(Email);
           var AllSettings = {InvoicesVM:InvoicesVM, EmailVM: EmailVM};
           //console.log(postData);
          $.ajax({
                //dataType: 'json',
               // async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Settings/SaveAllSettings",              
                data: JSON.stringify(AllSettings),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (response) {
                  toastr.success('Saved SuccessFully!');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                  //toastr.error('Cannot Save the Data!');
                }
            })

      }
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult SaveAllSettings([FromBody]SettingsVM AllSettings)
        {
           
            return Json("");
        }
```